# TypeError: unhashable type: 'set' множества через функцию

Tags: python

Когда я через функцию пытаюсь преобразовать множество, мне выдает ошибку TypeError: unhashable type: Set, вторая функция работает и обычный вывод тоже работает.

```
words = ({'hello2', 23, 23, 'mum', 'daddy1', 'father'})

wsr = set(words)
print(wsr)


# Кортеж -> Множества, Ошибка TypeError: unhashable type: 'set' 
def foo_four(*args):
    """"""
    #print((args), end=' '), print("- тип элемента: ", end=' '), print(type(args))
    lots = set(args)
    print((lots), end=' '), print("- тип элемента: ", end=' '), print(type(lots))

foo_four(words)


# Кортеж -> Множества, работает
def foo_four_one(x):
    """"""
    #print((args), end=' '), print("- тип элемента: ", end=' '), print(type(args))
    lots = set(x)
    print((lots), end=' '), print("- тип элемента: ", end=' '), print(type(lots))

foo_four_one(words)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда Вы используете `def foo_four_one(x):` у Вас `x` принимает значение `{'mum', 'hello2', 23, 'daddy1', 'father'}` и `set(множество)` выполняется без ошибок (собственно эта операция ничего не изменяет), а когда вы пытаетесь , то-же самое проделать с кортежем `({'mum', 'hello2', 23, 'daddy1', 'father'},)`, элементом которого является множество возникает исключение, поскольку единственным элементом кортежа `*args` является изменяемый объект `множество`